# Base64 implementation with bit shifting

Tags: c++, base64, implementation

I try to implement a base64 encoder. I have this algorithm:

```
while (len--)
{
    char_array_3[i++] = *(data++);

    if (i == 3)
    {
        char_array_4[0] = (char_array_3[0] & 252) >> 2; //This line.
        char_array_4[1] = ((char_array_3[0] & 3) << 4) + ((char_array_3[1] & 240) >> 4);
        char_array_4[2] = ((char_array_3[1] & 15) << 2) + ((char_array_3[2] & 192) >> 6);
        char_array_4[3] = char_array_3[2] & 63;

        for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            ret += base64_chars[char_array_4[i]];
        }
        i = 0;
    }
}
```

Why I should do `char_array_3[0] & 252`? I can use only `>> 2`. Since ...

For instance, if I put this character `H`:

`H -> 01001000`

I can do bit shift:
`01001000 >> 2 = 000100100`

Or use `and (&)`...

`252 -> 11111100`

`01001000 & 11111100 = 01001000` I will have the same digit...

And then need to do this:
`01001000 >> 2 = 000100100`

May I remove the number `252`, `3`, `240` etc.?

Comment: What do you mean by "and the other"? What other?

Comment: I would try to make this code readable first. For example replace decimal constants with hex.

Comment: @David Schwartz, I mean ```252```, ```3```, ```240```, ```15```, ```192``` and ```63```.

Comment: @lostsky25 If you think you can remove the `3` in `((char_array_3[0]&3)<<4)`, then you don't understand the code.

Comment: @Slava, In the first implementation I had
hexadecimal literals. I just changed to decimal literals.

Comment: @David Schwartz, Ok, what about ```252```?

Comment: You should not, it much easier to read binary in hex format.

Comment: What type is `char_array_3`?  Is it an array of `char` or `unsigned char`?  If it is a `signed char`, then you should keep the masks.  If the code is supposed to be portable, and the type is `char`, then you should keep the masks.  If it isn't `unsigned char`, it probably ought to be (or `std::uint8_t` or `std::byte`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> May I remove the number 252, 3, 240 etc.?

No, not all of them. In case of right shift and binary mask 252, 240 and 192 they are redundant and you can remove them. But 3 15 and 63 are not redundant, as you would propagate bits that you should not to.

Comment: Leaving the redundant constants there may make the code more understandable.  A good optimizer would recognize that they're redundant and remove them from the compiled code.

Comment: @MarkRansom I agree, but OP's question if he can remove them, not why they are there in the first place.

Comment: Yes, I removed the redundant digits. I got the same string... And I'll change decimal constants to hexdecimal.

Comment: "Why should I" was also part of the question.  Realize I wasn't complaining, just presenting a different point of view.

Comment: @MarkRansom ""Why should I" was also part of the question. ". Yea missed that, good point.